# Senior colleagues are deriding my work

Tags: work-environment, colleagues, relationships, careers

Let me give you some context before. I'm working in a very well-known international company as a DevOps Engineer with 6 months of experience. I feel so grateful and lucky to develop my skills and contribute to such company.

But there is an issue becoming more serious day by day. Some of my colleagues decry/look down upon my job and intentionally trying to find my mistakes even though my mentor is reviewing and refactoring them.

Let me give you some examples.

Last week, I was looking at my personal website about how much it got attention(I love writing blog posts, it motivates me) after shift. I was on a page which I explained differences between Linux, Minix, Unix and Posix. One of my senior colleagues laughed like I peed myself and told me "In 2018, why are you still writing things like that? It has already expired." I tried to explain that I wrote it, because I find it a convenient way to not forgetting and sharing them in my way. Of course he didn't even care and wanted to look further at my page. He saw an Ansible snippet and told me "Hahaha, an Ansible code! Let me find your mistakes." before even looking at it. He couldn't find any and got angrier. I didn't even know what to say to get out of that situation... The situations are similar when he sees my work. It demotivates me.

Another example is not much about deriding actually. One of my not senior colleagues this time, tells me that I don't need to work this much in a bullying way when he sees me working. I would like to point that I'm not a anti-social guy but I would like to finish my job and then go socialize with people. I don't like leaving half-done work and take look afterwards. But these kind of conversations make me don't want to talk with them.

What should I do to prevent these from happening without damaging my image, relations and career?

Comment: terrible situation to be in, you can't just ignore them until they get bored with hassling you?

Comment: @Kilisi This is what I'm doing right now but I'm not sure if I can continue this without going mad one day.

Comment: I've had a lot of hassling, I just put it down to jealousy and ignore it, if you can't do that, you might want to talk to your manager that you're feeling unhappy in your environment, manager may just tell them to stop being pricks. I wouldn't make a big thing out of it, you're very junior and expected to handle a bit of this sort of behaviour.

Comment: @Kilisi Funny thing, they don't treat me like a junior. They expect me to act and work like a senior. I believe this is actually a good thing in a way but it also puts some pressure on my shoulders. And about the manager talk, I think it is my last resort since he doesn't have enough management skills to deal with these kind of situations in my opinion... But I can give it a shot of course, maybe I am wrong.

Comment: I would just ignore it to be honest, eventually you prove your worth or someone new shows up to hassle and you become valued.

Comment: Respect if you can explain the differences between Linux, minix, unix and posix. Fun fact: My spelling checker knows Linux but not the others.

Comment: As @gnasher729 says, actually pointing out the differences between these systems is quite interesting, even if only from the perspective of history or evolution of operating systems. If your colleague is narrow-minded and isn't interested in the context of how systems developed, that's not your mistake. Ignore them, they are sad, poor people, without imagination.

Comment: Actually in some cases our classmates and colleagues feel jealous to our success. For me if you are satisfied than nothing matters. If you take these things serious than you will become under confident and dis oppinted.  So just ignore them and continue yourself to excel with full strength

Comment: First case : Developers pride & competition. Make it a game, make jokes and tease the guy when he acts that way. If he gets pissed at this, that's an unprofessional behavior. One of my former colleague was like this with everyone until he ackwnoledged the skill of the person. Second case : Coffee machine gossips IMHO. You can beat it by going to joining the afterwork beer (coffee/juice if you dont drink) if you are done with your work on the given day. Keep it professional. You'll be showing an other image of you and will see if it's about chemistry or just gossips that you'll prove wrong.

Comment: @Answers_Seeker What was described is not "developers pride and competition". What I saw was a sad man who knows he's a failure and the only way he gets his kicks is by picking on some new guy. (People who are actually good at what they are doing don't need to make themselves feel good by trying to put others down). There's a difference between "senior" and "employed for some time".

Comment: @gnasher729 : The generalization I made may not apply to this case but I faced some people making pejorative assumptions ("I'm going to find mistakes", "your technology is outdated")  like the ones in this post (which are about IT/Programming on this post) and, in those experiences, it always stopped when they acknowledged the guy's skill. Sometimes, those "failure boys" see it as teasing. I'm not legiting them, just trying to highlight some possibility. Completely agree on the figure that good people don't need to show it, as they usually hide it to keep the surprise advantage

Answer (score 4):

> One of my senior colleagues laughed like I peed myself and told me "In 2018, why are you still writing things like that? It has already expired."

There's two takes on this sort of behaviour - the "laugh along" reaction where you treat it as banter, or the "raised eyebrow" reaction where you treat it as though your colleague is just acting out of line & embarassing himself.

In your situation it sounds like the second would be most appropriate, since you don't enjoy that banter.

In that case, you can look at him, pause, raise an eyebrow, say something akin to "...right..." - and then move on. Most of the time with this reaction, in my experience, people either stop finding it fun, or get the hint and move on.

If it really persists after that, you can just be more direct and say "I'm sorry, I don't appreciate these sorts of comments - I don't find them funny. Can you stop?"

Answer (score 3):

That's a ridiculous situation to be in, for sure.

They do that because you have expose some gap on your general behavior. They identify on you some possible target to do this kind of things. It's not your fault, but you need to be aware that you are triggering this on this kind of (bad) person.

The first step to do is ignore them. You can stop the social conversations (like tell about your blog) and don't tell anymore about you to them, because this is munition for attack you. If they use some thing on work to attack you (like your code), just ask for them to tell what's wrong without joking and thank them for the review. Be professional here.

On your tasks, be more cautious about your code. If you take some code decision that could be more polemic, be sure to have some reference about the decision (StackOverflow post, Martin Fowler article, some book, etc). I already enter on a company that any kind of decision that I made was questioned by some person and, after some weeks, he relax and stop it. The objective here is not give any excuse to bother you. It's harsh, but works.

The second step is take care about the image that you pass for the people. Maybe you are a very nice and agreeable person, but this can be interpreted as a weakness. Utilize some situation on work to demonstrate that you are not so weak: be more direct, disagree when necessary, etc. Be serious. Of course, always with respect.

Answer (score 1):

For the first situation, that guy sounds like a jerk, and I'd be inclined to treat him like one.  When he says something like "Let me try to find your mistakes", you should just say "go ahead", and then when he fails to find any, you should grin as big as you can and say something like "see, I told you so, next time I'll try to find yours".  Whether to follow up on that is up to you (I would, but I'm also a more petty and vengeful person than most, so it's up to you).

As for the second issue, I don't really understand the problem.  Saying you don't need to work so much, and in a bullying way, sounds contradictory to me.  It sounds like your colleague wants you to join in on their social activities, but he sees you as being kind of antisocial.  When he invites you to join him, you should make an effort to checkpoint your work ASAP (get to a point where you can stop working for a bit and come back and quickly context-switch back into what you were doing) and join him.